# Custom user query - orderby meta_key (that may not exist)

Tags: mysql, meta-query, users, join-tables

I'm in need of someone who knows MySQL better than I do! I've started writing a custom statement, but I'm not an expert with mySQL and it's not quite there (I'm happy to scrap it entirely if there's a better way to do it!)

Here's what I'm *trying* to do...

Retrieve a SINGLE user_id where the users meta_key `_wcv_store_icon_id` has a value (not including empty string).
The results must be ordered by `promo_count`. 
The issue I'm having is that `promo_count` might not exist, but I'd like Lower (or non-existing `promo_count` to come first)

What I currently have:

```
SELECT u1.`user_id`
FROM `wp_usermeta` u1
LEFT JOIN `wp_usermeta` u2
ON u1.`user_id` = u2.`user_id`
WHERE (u1.`meta_key` = '_wcv_store_icon_id' AND u1.`meta_value` <> '')
AND u2.`meta_key` = 'promo_count'
GROUP BY u1.`user_id`
ORDER BY u2.`meta_value` ASC
LIMIT 1
```

---

For the record, I originally tried doing this with get_users but I simply couldn't get it working with any combination of meta_key, meta_value, or meta_query parameters... I think a custom query is definitely the way to go here, however I don't know enough to get it working.

Any suggestions are welcome! I'm at the end of my tether with this one :(

Comment: Try `WP_Meta_Query` https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: I've tried that - I'd really just like to know the mySQL statement required for the task because using WP_Meta_Query I need to have the `promo_count` exist before I can sort it by that value. If the promo_count doesn't exist, I'd like that use to be sorted to the top of the list.